# Accessing resources XML from another library project in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am trying to create a Xamarin.Android Component to send to the Xamarin Component Store, and I need to bundle my Colors.xml with it, so it is accessible to everyone using my component. I am setting the build action for the Colors.xml tp "AndroidResource".

So I created an Android sample application, when I add a reference to my library project's dll, I am able to use the colors defined, my project compiles and it runs, but I get no intellisense on Xamarin Studio. So that would be a bad thing for anyone using my library, as they would not be able to even see that the colors are available to use. You can see in this picture the colors defined are not available in the suggestions box.

[image]

If I add the Colors.xml directly into my project, I get Intellisense support, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the same result above when adding just the dll reference? Did I do something wrong or Xamarin.Android/Xamarin Studio doesn't support this kind of scenario?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I know this is a problem with Intellisense not being able to pick up the values, but is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: It is just Intellisense not picking it up. You can still access the resources though.

Comment: Yes, but is this expected? Can't I do anything to make the Intellisense work?